# spring mvc url rewrite by nginx

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, nginx, nginx-location

I'm using tag ***mvc:resources*** to handle static files in my spring mvc projects.

Well I want to rewrite urls for SEO using, such as ***/page?id=1*** >> ***/page/1.html*** .

[spring-context.xml]

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/view/css/"    mapping="/css/**" />
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/view/images/" mapping="/images/**" />
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/view/js/" mapping="/js/**" />
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/" mapping="/jsp/**" />
```

[nginx.conf]

```
rewrite      ^/page/(.*)(.html)$ /page?id=$1 last;
proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080/project/;
```

Problems:

All the static files will be added a prefix ***page***, absolutly it can not get the correct file,

such as 'localhost/js/index.js' becoming 'localhost/**page**/js/index.js'

So how could I solve this problem ? Any suggestions ?

I have tried using urlrewritefilter(org.tuckey) and get the same situation QAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure by now you would have found your response but I will answer for those after you who would be looking for the same answer.

```
location ~ ^/script/(.*)$ {
                        alias   /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/assets/js/$1;
                        autoindex off;
                }


    location ~ ^/styles/(.*)$ {
                        alias   /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/assets/css/$1;
                        autoindex off;
                }


    location ~ ^/images/(.*)$ {
                        alias   /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/assets/images/$1;
                        autoindex off;
                }
```

Above is the equivalent of in nginx of the the following spring resource mapping

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/assets/images/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**" location="/assets/css/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/script/**" location="/assets/js/"/>
```

Hope this helps

Best Regards,